# Eclipse Pro blem View showing Error Types I've filtered out

Tags: eclipse

I have something like 27001 errors, and they are all from generated files in an output folder. 90% of them are HTML Problems. I've gone into "Configure Contents" and deselected "HTML Problems" under types, but they still persisted. Then, I went and deselected ALL types, and they were still there. Am I misunderstanding what the 'types' is, or is this a bug?

Is there a solution or any workaround, maybe to remove specific folders from the path of what eclipse checks for warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: When I removed HTML problems from the view, it must have stopped checking anything to do with HTML problems. This included removing existing ones. Manually deleting all the errors from the problems view got rid of them.